# How can I speed up reading from socket for non-constant size data structures? Python

Tags: python, numpy, performance, sockets, struct

I need to communicate with the game (I can't change its code) over a TCP connection. The developers have provided code that can be used to do this. But I came to the conclusion that this python code is too slow, because data structures are read one primitive at a time:

```
bool <- socket_stream.read(1)
int <- socket_stream.read(4)
double <- socket_stream.read(8)
```

I'm looking for a pretty way to do it like this:

```
Structure <- socket_stream.read(N)
```

But there is a problem: the required buffer size is not constant, e.g. for the Game data structure:

```py
def read_from(stream: StreamWrapper) -> "Game":
        """Read Game from input stream
        """
        my_id = stream.read_int()
        players = []
        for _ in range(stream.read_int()):
            players_element = Player.read_from(stream)
            players.append(players_element)
        current_tick = stream.read_int()
        units = []
        for _ in range(stream.read_int()):
            units_element = Unit.read_from(stream)
            units.append(units_element)
        loot = []
        for _ in range(stream.read_int()):
            loot_element = Loot.read_from(stream)
            loot.append(loot_element)
        projectiles = []
        for _ in range(stream.read_int()):
            projectiles_element = Projectile.read_from(stream)
            projectiles.append(projectiles_element)
        zone = Zone.read_from(stream)
        sounds = []
        for _ in range(stream.read_int()):
            sounds_element = Sound.read_from(stream)
            sounds.append(sounds_element)
```

It refers to other structures, but they are simpler. This is what StreamWrapper looks like:

```py
class StreamWrapper:

    BOOL_FORMAT_STRUCT_PACK = struct.Struct("?").pack
    INT_FORMAT_STRUCT_PACK = struct.Struct("<i").pack
    LONG_FORMAT_STRUCT_PACK = struct.Struct("<q").pack
    FLOAT_FORMAT_STRUCT_PACK = struct.Struct("<f").pack
    DOUBLE_FORMAT_STRUCT_PACK = struct.Struct("<d").pack

    BOOL_FORMAT_STRUCT_UNPACK = struct.Struct("?").unpack
    INT_FORMAT_STRUCT_UNPACK = struct.Struct("<i").unpack
    LONG_FORMAT_STRUCT_UNPACK = struct.Struct("<q").unpack
    FLOAT_FORMAT_STRUCT_UNPACK = struct.Struct("<f").unpack
    DOUBLE_FORMAT_STRUCT_UNPACK = struct.Struct("<d").unpack

    # Reading primitives

    def read_bool(self) -> bool:
        return self.BOOL_FORMAT_STRUCT_UNPACK(self.stream.read(1))[0]

    def read_int(self) -> int:
        return self.INT_FORMAT_STRUCT_UNPACK(self.stream.read(4))[0]

    def read_long(self) -> int:
        return self.LONG_FORMAT_STRUCT_UNPACK(self.stream.read(8))[0]

    def read_float(self) -> float:
        return self.FLOAT_FORMAT_STRUCT_UNPACK(self.stream.read(4))[0]

    def read_double(self) -> float:
        return self.DOUBLE_FORMAT_STRUCT_UNPACK(self.stream.read(8))[0]
```

I want to use `np.ndarray(shape, dtype=some_structured_dtype, buffer=stream.read(length), offset=offset...)` OR `numpy.frombuffer(stream.read(length), dtype=some_structured_dtype, count=count, offset=offset)`

But I can’t figure out exactly how to do it beautifully so that it really speeds up reading the data.

Run function: all `.read_from(...)` like the one I presented above. `.write_to()` also worries me, but I'll deal with it myself...

```py
def run(self):
    strategy = None
    debug_interface = DebugInterface(self.reader, self.writer)

    while True:
        message = ServerMessage.read_from(self.reader)

        if isinstance(message, ServerMessage.GetOrder):
            order = strategy.get_order(message.player_view, debug_interface if message.debug_available else None)
            ClientMessage.OrderMessage(order).write_to(self.writer)
            self.writer.flush()

        elif isinstance(message, ServerMessage.UpdateConstants):
            strategy = TrackingStrategy(message.constants)

        elif isinstance(message, ServerMessage.Finish):
            strategy.finish()
            break

        elif isinstance(message, ServerMessage.DebugUpdate):
            strategy.debug_update(message.displayed_tick, debug_interface)
            ClientMessage.DebugUpdateDone().write_to(self.writer)
            self.writer.flush()
        else:
            raise Exception("Unexpected server message")
```

Comment: It is unclear what `socket_stream.read` actually does, i.e. if it actually causes a read on the socket each time (i.e. system calls involved) or if it instead is a buffered reader which only reads data in larger chunks from the socket and then returns most "read" calls from the memory buffered data. The latter is pretty effective. *"I came to the conclusion that this python code is too slow, ..."* - is this just your guess because it looks inefficient for you, or did you actually check that this is the part of your program which really needs performance optimization?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I came to this conclusion by peering into the profiler. The absolute part (75%) of cumtime goes to the `{method 'read' of '_io.BufferedRWPair' objects}`. and of tottime to the `{method 'recv_into' of '_socket.socket' objects}`. Also the `self.stream` object is a instance of `socket.makefile()` from standard library.
like `self.reader = StreamWrapper(socket.socket().makefile('rwb'))`

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, maybe their game just doesn't run at full TPS on my machine...
But I was looking for similar issues with reading in `struct`. There, the use of `numpy` gave a 30x improvement.

Comment: Typically you **would** do it like this but with some automatic buffering so that every call to read is not a separate system call. I guess Python doesn't have an equivalent of Java's BufferedInputStream...

Answer (score 2):

Reading data item per item (from 1 to 8 bytes) is not efficient in Python. You should decode them in a packed way. This is often but not always possible. For example, if you read a string with a prefixed size, then you must read the size in the first place and if the string is zero-terminated then it starts to be tricky to do that efficiently in Python (one need to deal with look-ahead buffers).

The default implementation of Python (CPython) is an interpreter so function calls are not optimized (like a native code would be) nor attribute fetches. The `read_bool` function is pretty expensive because of:

- Initial function call (`read_bool`)
- Fetch of `self.BOOL_FORMAT_STRUCT_UNPACK`
- Fetch of `self.stream.read` (2 values)
- 2 function calls (`self.stream.read` and `self.BOOL_FORMAT_STRUCT_UNPACK`)
- A possible **system call** to `read` (if there is no buffering)
- Creation+reference-counting of the output object (byte array)
- Indexing of the byte array and creation+reference-counting of an integer

In fact calling `read_bool` already takes about 160 ns on my system without the `read` system call...

Instead, you can use composite data-types. For example : `struct.unpack('!BII', b'\x14\x47\x94\xAB\x27\x74\x29\xC7\x11')`. This takes 150 ns on my machine, but to decode 3 values in a row. The bigger the structure, the better the speedup.

Using Numpy array to decode values one by one will not be faster. in fact it will certainly be slower because Numpy is not optimized for that and each function call to Numpy suffer from a big overhead (regarding the operation). Numpy only worth it if you deal with repeated elements of the same type. More specifically, the function `view` can be helpful for that as well as `np.frombuffer` (to be called once as it is expensive).

If you need to decode the buffer item per item due to the way the protocol is designed, then you need to use a *native code*. You can use Cython to to that easily. In this case, you should read the TCP stream **chunk by chunk** so to avoid system calls (or even calls to the libc). Message should be decoded when the buffer is large enough.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll try Cython and report back when I get the result.